# Go REPL: prints input prompt once more after SIGINT signal

Tags: go, input, output, read-eval-print-loop, sigint

I've written a simple REPL using Go's `fmt` package. When interrupting the program using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the infinite loop prints the prompt once more, which I think shouldn't be possible.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  for true {
    input := ""

    fmt.Print("Input> ")
    fmt.Scanln(&input)

    fmt.Println("You typed: " + input)
  }
}
```

Here's what it looks like running the program:

```
Input> test
You typed: test
Input> (Pressing Ctrl+C here)
Input>
C:\Users\wgumenyuk>
```

Is there a reason why the prompt is being printed once more after terminating the program?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The shell is adding the extra output, not the Go program.

Comment: Interesting, and thanks for your quick response! Do you know a way of preventing this behaviour? Or is this something that cannot be changed?